# Tikz getting jagged line when plotting polar function

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seems like one of the functions I'm using has a piecewise representation in tikz?

I tried with more sample points, but it did not improve.

I'm getting these jagged edges in my plot. I have no idea why. It should be smooth like this [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20-ln%28tan%28%28phi%29%2F%282%29%29%29):

[image: smooth]

But instead, Its jagged.

But for the values with x greater than 0.5*pi it is smooth. can I set some options in pgf to not approximate the log and trig functions maybe?

[image: jagged]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw [->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw [->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[domain= 0.01*pi:0.99*pi,scale=1.5,samples=600] plot ({deg(\x)}:{-1*ln(tan(\x/2 r))});
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `samples=60`

Comment: Or even `samples=30` but adding option `smooth`

Comment: still doesn't look right with fewer samples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default implementation of function `ln` in tikz (actually `pgfmath`) is rather basic and not accurate enough. Installing the floating-point calculation only for `ln` will give smoother calculation results hence fixes the problem.

Quoting [Henri Menke's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578402/tikz-getting-jagged-line-when-plotting-polar-function/578408?noredirect=1#comment1455728_578408):

> It should be noted that `fpu` doesn't actually give you more accuracy (i.e. decimal digits) but significantly increases the range of accessible numbers.

Note the option `/pgf/fpu/install only` is available since pgf-tikz v3.1.6.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fpu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{/pgf/fpu/install only=ln}
  \draw [->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw [->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[domain= 0.01*pi:0.99*pi,scale=1.5,samples=600] 
    plot ({deg(\x)}:{-1*ln(tan(\x/2 r))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that `fpu` doesn't actually give you more accuracy (i.e. decimal digits) but significantly increases the range of accessible numbers.

Comment: Updating pgf and using `fpu` was indeed working